# Meaning of "educational showcase" and surrounding sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Our teacher gave us this line in the end of our assignment (Project):

> "As part of an educational advisory team you have been asked to create
>   an educational showcase about an emerging technology."

But as I am not a native speaker, I am just taking it as like they ask us questions about technology and about our project and our topic related questions.

How to interpret it?

Comment: The word "showcase" needs to be clarified by your teacher.  Ask your teacher: what type of presentation or exhibit would he/she consider to be a "showcase"?

Comment: @ARG The key point is *you have been **asked** to **create** a showcase*. That sentence doesn't ask you a question. Depending on the context, *have been asked* could be used ether to tell you to create a showcase, or to discuss about a showcase you have already made. Considering your reaction, the first is likelier (i.e. they ask you to create a new showcase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to understand is the definition of [showcase](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/showcase) used:

> 2) anything displaying someone or something to good advantage   ⇒ "the revue was a showcase for new talent"

So it is about creating an educational display (of some kind) to positively describe some topic. That topic needs to be about an emerging technology.

*part of an educational advisory team* is the point of view you are being asked to take. Something like:

> If you were an educational advisor, what kind of educational showcase about an emerging technology, would you create?

You are being asked to answer that question.

Comment: But, it depends on what the teacher meant by *"showcase"* right ? It could mean creating a presentation, or making a model or taking a session or a class, or anything else. If you ask me, the teacher should be wee bit more specific